# Difference between y against x, x^2 and sqrt(y) against x in a linear model

Tags: regression, correlation, linear-model

Suppose that we have a response variable y which is known to have a quadratic relationship
with a predictor variable x. What are the differences between fitting a linear model of y
against x and x^2, versus a linear model of sqrt(y) against x?

My theory is that y against x^2 will look similar or even same as sqrt(y) against x depending on the dataset?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Have you tried it and looked at the results?

Comment: Consider the quadratic relationship $Y = x^2 - 1 + \varepsilon.$ Ideally, when the error $\varepsilon$ is small and $-1\lt x \lt 1,$ this model will result in observations $Y \lt 0.$  How do you propose to take the square root??